# How is the G constant calculated in the cryptonote protocol?

Tags: cryptonote, cryptography, algorithm

The cryptonote whitepaper uses a G constant, as a base point, to calculate various operations, but I don't understand where this constant actually comes from. Is it just a random point on an elliptical curve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

G is defined in the definition of the signature scheme, [Edwards-curve Digital Signature Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA) (EdDSA)in the case of Cryptonote and Monero.

As explained in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27392) in crypo.SE :

> the base point is chosen pretty arbitrarily. As described in the Ed25519 paper, it arises from the choice u=9 in the original Curve25519 paper

The details of this choice are probably out of the scope of Monero.SE and more suited to [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).